# addition of positive and negative numbers

Tags: java, int

Hi was just trying to figure out in mathematics 1 divide by 2 is 0.5 and there is no remainder
in java 1 divide by 2 is it one or 0. I'm having problems understanding the code below which is suppose to add up the numbers from 1 to 10 which includes negative numbers. can anybody help please.

```
System.out.println("1+ - 2 + 3 + - 4 + 5 +- 6 + 7  +- 8 + 9 +- 10");
        int sum = 0, x;
        for(j = 1 ; j < 11 ; j++)
        {
            if(j % 2 == 0)
                x = -1 * j;
            else
                x = j;

            sum = sum + x;
        }
        System.out.println("Answer =  " + sum);
```

Comment: Learn Java's arithmetic operator working and then ask specifically what portion of code you didn't understand!

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: That looks to me like it's a taylor series for some sort of trigonometric function

Comment: The text of your question indicates a confusion about the difference between integer and floating point arithmetic in Java, but the code you posted has nothing to do with that.  What, specifically, don't you understand?  Are you confused about how the modulo operator works?

Comment: and what does division have to do with the code that you're trying to understand?

Comment: im trying to understand in java 1 divide by 2 is it o or 1

Comment: It's definitely not `o`, unless `o == 0`. Also, it's "I'm", not "im". When you write unary minus operators (`-2`, `-6`) you should put them next to the number or variable they are negating. `5 +- 6` is a very confusing way of writing `5 + -6`.

Comment: @ColinAnacoura why do u wanna know about the division of 1 by 0, what's the common point with this division and the code you posted?

Comment: I'm getting trouble with adding up negative and positive numbers numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first `println` is trying to say I'm gonna sum numbers from 1 to 10 but be careful to add the even numbers as negative numbers

So as the even numbers are negative, The code is trying to first check if it's an even number by

```
(j % 2 == 0)
```

If it's an even then it multiply the number by -1 in order to create a negative even number,

```
 x = -1 * j;
```

otherwise(odd number) it use the exact number,

```
x = j;
```

Finally it add up all the numbers

```
sum = sum + x;
```